# jquery messi addon help needed using load method

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

Im trying to use messi jquery script on my site but I am unsure of how the load method it uses passes params on.

The example messi gives for creating a ajax call popup is:

```
Messi.load('test2.php', {params: {user: 'demo', password: '1234'}});
```

but i've tried both post and get method to capture the parameters in test2.php but without success.

for example

```
$user=$_POST['user'];
```

and

```
$get=$_GET['user'];
```

but both return a undefined index error

The load method is supposed to be an ajax call so I presumed it would be either a post or get request.

Is there another way I can capture the parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
$user = $_REQUEST['user'];
```

Anyway, have you loaded before jQuery? Messi script needs it to work!

Or, you can call your ajax request externally, then load a Messi popup with the ajax response.

```
$.get( "test2.php", { user: "username", password: "234234" } )
.done(function( data ) {
    Messi.alert(data);
});
```

(if you take a look on the github Messi's library, that code makes an ajax call and then opens a Messi alert. This is the js library not minified: https://github.com/marcosesperon/Messi/blob/master/messi.js#L256 )

Comment: yes, ive loaded jquery before the messi script. I've got the popup working, its only the problem with picking up the parameters that i'm having.

Comment: $user = $_REQUEST['user']; didn't work either, still getting an undefined index.

Comment: Did you try with $_REQUEST?
Anyway, calling the GET request and then opening the messi alert, you can be sure that data into php page is coming from a GET/POST request (depends on what function you want to use)

Comment: Can you post your php page? (only the piece of code from the GET request and the echo)
Are you echoing something? Ajax call waits something echoed from the php page.

Comment: Doing the request first then loading it into the popup works a treat. I actually prefer it that way. Thanks everyone for your help

Comment: I would if I knew how to :-)

Comment: Lol, just press on the tick icon that becomes green when you hover on it just under "1 Answer" at the top of it :)